# Funky tripod for Handy recorders

Tags: tripod

Hi,

I just came across this site with accessories for cameras which are quite useful for sound designers with handy recorders

http://asia.cnet.com/smart-camera-guide-for-social-networking-addicts-62210075.htm

Answer (score 2):

I own a Gorillapod and use it with my H4N, it's really convenient but it's noticeable that the H4N is a tiny bit heavy for what the gorillapod was intended to hold. I'm sure an H2 or H1 will be perfect with it. I think there's a bigger one intended for SLR's that would work better with heavy recorders.

Comment: Gorillapod SLR FTW. Works even with the Sony PCM-D50. The weight capacities for those non-SLR models are woefully overspec'd.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem as WillH... my h4n is too heavy for my WalMart brand "Gorillapod," unless I'm spreading the legs insanely wide.

Also, the EyeFi cards don't work with the h4n, or most other handheld recorders.

That's a great article for point-and-shoot camera enthusiasts, but only one product really works for handheld recorders.

The wireless SD card reader looks interesting, though.